# Custom message box with only OK button in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, localization, messagebox

I'm developing windows phone 8 application. The application should work in two languages English and Arabic.

**In some pages I need to show message with OK and CANCEL buttons. So for this I have used the Custom Message Box. According to the language the text is displaying i.e. either in English or Arabic. So Everything is fine.**

**Now in some pages I have to show message with OK button only. So how should I display Custom Message Box with OK button.**

**NOTE:** why I am using Custom Message Box is Button's text I can change based on the user language i.e. I can display text in English or Arabic.

Comment: Why did you ask this question twice, with different titles?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.Show method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms598690%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which takes three arguments.  The last argument is the MessageBoxButton enum, which specifies which buttons to show.

```
 MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText: "Your data was saved.", 
                 caption: "Your custom caption.", 
                 button: MessageBoxButton.OK);
```